# Set timer on Get Lock (SVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi I was wondering if there is a way for the SVN server to automatically release and commit the Get Lock function on any file after a certain amount of time.

for example; if a developer locked a file to work on, and forgot to release the lock, in 10 mins the lock will be automatically released.

We have a big numbers of developers here and if one forgot to release a lock it might be a problem and then we will have to use either "steal" or "break" which are nor very safe neither efficient

Comment: Hmm.. This is actually a very good question and doing a bit of digging in the svn manuals, it seems like at the very least, an expire date is supported: **"Lock Created (date) - Lock Expires (date)"** .. But there's no reference in the manuals anywhere on how to set this property. I may have to sniff my source code checkout of svn and see if I can find where it can be invoked. Good question.

Comment: I'd do it now, but unfortunately I can't look at the moment since I'm at work and don't have it on hand. Maybe if someone else has done a bit of digging, they can answer as well.

Comment: First I would ask why are you using locks and on what kind of files?

Comment: Why should it be better to release a lock after a certain time as to steal or break it?

Comment: @Chris thanks for the response, if you figure out anything please share it

Comment: @royalTS because if you steal or break a lock, you would not be sure that the person working on the file is already done, but if the whole department knows that in some certain amount of time the lock will vanish, one would wait to be on the safe side

Comment: @MostafaMekky Maybe I am missing something, but I am still see no difference... How do you want to determine the time for a lock to vanish? Different task take different time... If you are working on a something and it takes longer than the lock time, the same problem as is someone steals your lock occurs...

Comment: @royalTS What you are missing is that, before the lock vanishes, the very recent changes will be commited. By "vanishing a lock", I actually mean commiting.